# C++ Templates: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I am trying to build a library with a templated class having a constraint on the value of the integer passed:

library.h

```
template<int N>
requires (N == 1)
class example {

public:

    example();

};
```

library.cpp:

```
#include "library.h"
```

main.ccp:

```
#include "library.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

However, when trying to compile `main.cpp`, the compiler throws me the following error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
```

I noticed that if I do not include `library.h` in `main.ccp`, the build compiles successfully, but I have nothing else in my main.ccp and I am not really sure what is happening.

I appreciate any help solving the issue as I cannot continue working on this if I cannot compile.

Comment: Whatever you do to solve that problem note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file please!

Comment: Your example builds correctly in a recent GCC.  Check that your compiler has C++20 support enabled.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that's actually not an issue here.

Comment: The `requires` keyword seems to be new since C++20. I just checked the GCC version that comes with Ubuntu Linux: That version does not support C++20 and it reports exactly the error message that you can see if you try to use the `requires` keyword.

Comment: I am using g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) version 10.2.0.

Comment: Are you using the command-line parameter `-std=c++20` in your g++ line?

Comment: I have installed a new compiler and it seems to be working without issues now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Charles Savoie already wrote in his comment, the `requires` keyword is new since C++ version 20.

Older compilers do not know that keyword; for such compilers `requires` is just an identifier like `example` or `helloWorld`.

You might try to replace `requires` by `helloWorld` to check if your compiler supports `requires`:

```
template<int N>
helloWorld (N == 1)
class example {
  public:
    example();
};
```

Of course, this will cause *some* error message in any case.

However, if you get *exactly the same* error message that you get now, it is very probable that your compiler does not support the `requires` keyword.

You can try to get a newer compiler, of course.

But in this case, it is probable that your library can only be used by the latest compilers so you will also require a very recent compiler when you write a program that uses your library.

If you want your library to be compatible with less recent compilers, you must avoid the `requires` keyword.